# In Meson, can I avoid to continuously jump from the source to the build directory and back?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, meson-build, out-of-source

To do an out-of-source build in Meson:

```
cd /path/to/source/
mkdir ../builddir
```

Then:

```
cd /path/to/source/
meson ../builddir
cd ../builddir
ninja
```

Is it possible to do anything like this (from `builddir`):

```
meson --pathToSource ../source     // pseudocode
ninja
```

I.e. avoid jumping from the source to the build directory and back.

For CMake, this is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've run `meson` to create build directory (which `meson` can create automatically), there is no need to run it everytime you change *meson.build*. When you run `ninja`, meson [can regenerate](http://mesonbuild.com/Running-Meson.html#building-the-source) build configurations itself depending on the changes in the sources.

To run `ninja` in other places than build directory, you can you `-C` option (from `ninja -h`):

> -C DIR   change to DIR before doing anything else

Given your example, it will be:

```
$ cd /path/to/source/
$ meson ../builddir
$ ninja -C ../builddir
```

Comment: Do you mean that if I add a new file to my project, and update the `meson.build` file, I do not need to launch meson again?

Comment: @Pietro yes, running `ninja` within meson-generated project will update build files for `ninja` (from `meson.build`) if it's necessary. I don't really sure about other backends..